# How to change NaNs in dataframe to 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I joined two data frames, and now have values in columns that say "NaN." I am trying to convert those cells to 0.

I have tried this:

```
df = final_data_frame.apply(to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

but I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'to_numeric' is not defined
```

Comment: provide sample data

Comment: The issue does not appear about replacing the NaNs to zero but with `dataframe.apply`